# Singleton with class in ES6

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, singleton

why we get true here, I understand the concept of the singleton, but anyway myCount1 and myCount2 are assigned to the same object, but two objects cant be equal anyway, so why we get true in the end, here is the code:

```
class Counter{
  constructor(){
    if(typeof Counter.instance==="object"){
      return Counter.instance;
    }
    this.count=0;
    Counter.instance= this;
    return this;
  }

  getCounter(){
    return this.count;
  }

  increaseCounter(){
    return this.count++;
  }
}
const myCount1 = new Counter();
const myCount2 = new Counter();
console.log(myCount1===myCount2) //true , why??
```

Comment: Because it's a singleton, not two different objects, that's the whole idea?

Comment: Notice that `myCount1 == Counter.instance` and `myCount2 == Counter.instance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they refer to the same object in memory (thats what a Singleton is for). If you have

```
let a = {}
let b = {}
```

Then they are not ===.
Its like referential equality in java.

```
String a ="ab";
String b = StringBuilder("ab").toString();
Then a != b
```

Comment: I understand that, but I cant full understand why it works like that, I mean that in the stage when the assignment is done to variables there are two objects assigned to each variable, and on the second line when we compare them what compiler do, it checks that there is only one created in the heap instead of manually assigned two? like this?

Comment: "*there are two objects assigned to each variable*" - no, there are not. Think of `const a = {}; const b = a;`. Are `a` and `b` two distinct variables? Yes. Do they hold different objects? No. So what would the result of `a === b` be?